# Can you extend aliases and - if so - how?

Tags: php, namespaces

I haven't had much experience with namespaces, my only cases being using Laravel.

```
<?php

use My\Full\Classname as Another; // <-- Alias
// Want to add in import here to extend Faker alias to include more methods
```

Say there is a package that has multiple useful classes.  How would I stack them under a single alias?  Can you extend aliases like you can in a class definition?

`class Foo extends Bar {}`

```
use My\Full\Classname as Another;    // Has bar() method
use My\Different\Foo extends Another // Has foo() method
```

I would like to be able to extend another so I can do Another->foo();  Is that possible with aliases?

Comment: By default you should be able to call `$faker->sentence()` just fine.

Comment: @prd for some reason it was throwing the error.  I removed the sentence() method and ran my seeders.  I just went back and added it and it worked.  Weird.  I'll change my example because it's still something I'm curious about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would just be done by creating a new class

```
class ExtendedAnother extends Another {
    function foo() {
        $this->bar();
        // Do foo here
    }
}
```

Now you are merely able to do the following

```
use ExtendedAnother as Another; // Has foo() method
Another->foo();
```

Aliases or namespaces aren't meant for class extension and as thus cannot be used in the way you are requesting.